# Minimizing the sum of squared errors in linear regression (proof/matrix notation)

Tags: regression

I'd appreciate you helping me understanding the proof of minimizing the sum of squared errors in linear regression models using matrix notation. I'm trying to derive [image] by minimizing the sum of squared errors,

[image]

Look at this [proof](https://www.econstats.com/RegressionOut_2_0.htm),

```
The q.c.e. basic equation in matrix form is: 
  y = Xb + e
  where y (dependent variable) is (nx1) or  (5x1)
        X (independent vars) is (nxk) or  (5x3)
        b (betas) is (kx1) or  (3x1)
        e (errors) is (nx1) or  (5x1)
Minimizing sum or squared errors using calculus results in the OLS eqn:
  b=(X'X)-1.X'y
To minimize the sum of squared errors of
a k dimensional line that describes the relationship 
between the k independent variables and y we
find the set of slopes (betas) that minimizes
Σ_{i=1 to n} e_i^2
Re-written in linear algebra we seek to min e'e
Rearranging the regression model equation, we get e = y - Xb
So e'e = (y-Xb)'(y-Xb) = y'y - 2b'X'y + b'X'Xb   (see Judge et al (1985) p14 )
Differentiating by b we get 0 = - 2X'y + X'Xb -> 2X'Xb=2X'y
Rearranging, dividing both sides by 2 -> b = X'X-1X'y
```

it is stated that if you rewrite the summation expression above, it is

[image]

Is any summation over a squared vector/matrix the product of the transpose with the vector/matrix itself?

Further in the proof, e is substituted by Y-X*beta, and e'e is differentiated with respect to beta, yielding this expression

[image]

and it is stated that this is equal to

[image]

Does anybody know where the second 2 comes from? If I rearrange it, it yields X'X*beta = 2X'Y without the 2 in front of the lefthand side of the equation.

Thank you!

Comment: (1) You know how when you differentiate $x^2$ "a two comes out in front" and you get $2x$? The same happens in matrix calculus so when you differentiate b'X'Xb for b, you get 2X'Xb. They left that 2 out (typo), they should have written 0 = - 2X'y + 2X'Xb. Both twos should be there.

Comment: (2) When $x$ and $y$ are vectors $x' y$ is the inner product of $x$ and $y$. And yes, the inner product of a vector with itself (i.e. $e' e$) is equal to the sum of squares of the elements. But if $x$ or $y$ are matrices, it is not the case.

Comment: Thank you very much noob2!